# How can I resolve java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.helpers.collection.Iterables.toList(Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/util/List?

Tags: java, netbeans, neo4j-embedded

I'm trying insert nodes in neo4j using embedded neo4j in java, but I obtain this error, i'm using neo4j 3.1.1 and netbeans 7

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.helpers.collection.Iterables.toList(Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/util/List;
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.<init>(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:49)
    at twitter4j.EmbeddeNeo4j.createDb(EmbeddeNeo4j.java:41)
```

I don't know if the problem in variable `DB_PATH = "D:\\Neo4j CE 3.1.1\\graph database"`
what should the variable `DB_PATH` be contained?
the code is :

```
void createDb() {
        clearDb();
        // start DB
        graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
        registerShutdownHook(graphDb);

        // start Transaction
        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        try {
            // adding data
            firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
            firstNode.setProperty("message", "Hello, ");
            secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
            secondNode.setProperty("message", "World!");

            relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo(secondNode, RelTypes.KNOWS);
            relationship.setProperty("message", "brave Neo4j ");

            // reading data
            System.out.println(firstNode.getProperty("message"));
            System.out.println(relationship.getProperty("message"));
            System.out.println(secondNode.getProperty("message"));

            greeting = (String) firstNode.getProperty("message") + (String) relationship.getProperty("message") + (String) secondNode.getProperty("message");

            Iterator<Relationship> it = firstNode.getRelationships().iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                Relationship r = it.next();
                Node[] nodes = r.getNodes();
                System.out.println(nodes[0].getProperty("message") + " " + r.getProperty("message") + " " + nodes[1].getProperty("message"));
            }

            tx.success();
        } finally {
            tx.terminate();
        }

    }

private void clearDb() {
    try {
        FileUtils.deleteRecursively(new File(DB_PATH));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like incompatible jars

Comment: Which neo4j jars do you have in your classpath?

Comment: i have this jar file neo4j-graphdb-api-3.0.1.jar

Comment: the problem is not in versions, I download the same version but the errors persist.

Comment: Did you fix this? I am getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.ArrayMap.<init>(BZZ)V in the same place of the code.

Comment: I am having the same problem on all 3.2.* versions, also on the line

`GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();`

Answer (score 0):

I had essentially this same problem; it was caused by the presence of older versions of Neo4J in the CLASSPATH along with the new one I was trying to use. (I learned along the way that my IDE doesn't clean out old targets before building new ones, which is why the older versions were there.)

Make sure that you've flushed out all older versions of the relevant .jars.