# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.helpers.collection.Iterables.toList(Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/util/List;

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, neo4j

I'm trying to run a simple cypher query in java and I'm receiving above error  when I try to run my application. I'm using intelliJ as my IDE. I'm recognizing that is  something related to missing of some dependencies but dont know exactly what.

My dependencies in POM.XML looks like

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-graphdb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-alpha02</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Sounds like JAR file incompatibility. Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203502/how-can-i-resolve-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-neo4j-helpers-collection-iter#45855479?

Comment: Why are you using different version of Neo4j : 3.2.0 & 3.2.0-alpha8 & 1.9.2 ? Moreover the root pom of neo4j (wich also contains neo4j-graphdb-api & kernel by transitivity) is provided and not the others ...